# How do I analytically find a HPD interval for the normal posterior?

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, posterior

I want to analytically find the HPD interval for a posterior that has the normal distribution $\mathbb{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. So according to the definition of the HPD interval I am looking for expressions for the upper and lower limit such that the integral of the posterior over these limits is equal to $1-\alpha$. Would really appreciate some guidance on this as I am struggling.

Answer (score 1):

If the posterior is a $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution, the HPD region is defined as
$$\mathfrak{H}_\alpha = \{\theta;\ \varphi(\theta;\mu,\sigma)\ge k_\alpha\}$$
or
$$\mathfrak{H}_\alpha = \{\theta;\ \sigma^{-2}(\theta-\mu)^2\le k'_\alpha\}= \{\theta;\ |\theta-\mu|\le \sigma k'_\alpha\}$$
meaning it is the symmetric credible region
$$\mathfrak{H}_\alpha = (\mu+\sigma q_{\alpha/2},\mu-\sigma q_{\alpha/2})$$
when $q_{\alpha/2}$ is the $\alpha/2$-quantile of the standard $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ distribution.